# Error with installing svnX (TortoiseSVN alternatives for mac)

Tags: tortoisesvn, svnx

I'm trying to install svnX 1.3.4dmg for iMac. It says **“svnX” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.** how can I do that. please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These instructions are for OSX Yosemite, and may not apply to all versions of OSX. Let me know if you need directions for another version. Also, a warning to anyone attempting to do this with potentially unsafe software, please be sure the program you are installing is legitimate and safe prior to running the installer. See the article linked below for more information about this topic.

To override your security settings and open the app anyway:

```
1. In the Finder, locate the app you want to open.

2. Don’t use Launchpad to do this. Launchpad doesn’t allow you to access the shortcut menu.

3. Press the Control key, then click the app icon, then choose Open from the shortcut menu.

4. Click Open.

The app should then be saved as an exception to your security settings, and you can open it in the future by double-clicking it just as you can any registered app.
```

Here is the Apple Support article I took this information from: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18657?locale=en_US

If anyone is curious, these are the keywords I used to search for solution (Google):

```
Mac OSX install program bypass unidentified publisher
```

Comment: @anuk, happy to help!